# PresentViewController a non full screen UIViewController with UINavigationController in it

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to present a UIViewController which is not full screen. It should be of custom size & not what can be achieved using modalPresentationStyle.

I wanted to create a view like the native Twitter/Facebook sharing sheet's size with UINavigationController so that I can push/pop more UIViewControllers. It should work for iPhone and iPad.

Comment: What are you going to display in that view controller.

Comment: these days, just use containers, http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use View Controller Containment to do this.  See "Implementing A Container View Controller" at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html for more info.  Basically you just need to call addChildViewController: before adding the child's view to your view, and removeFromParentViewController: before removing it.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was roughly:

```m
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None // Otherwise the sub view might go under the parent's navigation bar

    let vc = MyPresentedViewController()
    self.addChildViewController(vc)
    self.view.addSubView(vc.view)
}
```

and it seemed to work ok.